# Unable to Include a Select Field in a Popover

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am dropping to include a select menu inside of a popover but every time I try the popover content block is blank. The popover is attached to a side menu item. 
Here is code I am using to build part of the side menu and want the popover to be on "Date History":

```
<li class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-navicon"></i> <span>History Settings</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> <span>Version History</span>
              <span class="pull-right-container">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
              </span>
            </a></li>
            <li><a id="dateHistoryPop" data-toggle="popover">
              <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> <span>Date History</span>
              <span class="pull-right-container">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
              </span>
            </a>
                  <div class="head hide" style="display:none">Date History</div>
                  <div class="content hide">
                        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                           <option>1</option>
                           <option>2</option>
                           <option>3</option>
                           <option>4</option>
                        </select>
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">
                     Submit
                     </button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

I also added the following to the bottom of my page:

```
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    title: function () {
        return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();
    },
    content: function () {
        return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass element in a `content` parameter instead of a string:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
  html: true,
  title: function () {
    return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();
  },
  content: function () {
    return $(this).parent().find('.content').children();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following solution: https://jsfiddle.net/shrewmouse/ex6tuzm2/4/

I inserted a select form in place of the number form and it works great.

```
<div class='_content' id='blah'>
  <select class="form-control">
     <option>option 1</option>
     <option>option 2</option>
     <option>option 3</option>
     <option>option 4</option>
     <option>option 5</option>
   </select>
 </div>
```